# PostgreSQL query joining a table and using json_agg() to get nested json output

Tags: json, postgresql, join, endpoint

So i have to tables i would like to join but get an error.

The tables look like this.
patterns table:

| patternUuid | urlName | title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1b3d8a0f-2bc3-4c50-a00a-6cf99335dd20 | card-fraud | Credit Card Fraud |
| 04bdcd7b-d61b-45cc-b9ea-c2decc77c852 | return-policy-fraud | Return Policy Fraud |

members table:

| id | memberId | patternsUuid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1b3d8a0f-2bc3-4c50-a00a-6cf99335dd20 |
| 2 | 2 | 1b3d8a0f-2bc3-4c50-a00a-6cf99335dd20 |
| 3 | 3 | 04bdcd7b-d61b-45cc-b9ea-c2decc77c852 |
| 4 | 3 | 04bdcd7b-d61b-45cc-b9ea-c2decc77c852 |

my sql that gives me an error

```sql
    SELECT "patternspatternUuid", "patterns.urlName", patterns.title, json_agg(members.memberId)
    FROM public.patterns
    JOIN members
    ON members.patternsUuid = patterns.patternUuid
    GROUP BY patterns.patternUuid
```

The error msg:

> ERROR:  column members.patternsuuid does not exist
> LINE 4: ON members.patternsUuid = patterns.patternUuid
> ^
> HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "members.patternsUuid".

At the end I what to call this query and make it and endpoint and a res in json to look like this:

```json
    "patterns": [
    {
      "patternUuid": "1b3d8a0f-2bc3-4c50-a00a-6cf99335dd20",
      "title": "Credit Card Fraud",
       "urlName": "card-fraud"
      "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit",
      "members": [
        {
          "memberId": 1
        },
        {
          "memberId": 2
        }
      ],
    },
```

Comment: Hi @Frederik Nielsen , can you add sample data like [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post) instead of snaphots

Comment: Hi @josephjacobmorris here you go, dont now why it not format to html table

Comment: column names in PostgreSQL  are insensitive (stored internally in the database as lowercase) by default but if they are quoted they become case-senstive like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive).  so `patternsUuid` and `"patternsUuid"` have  different case for database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my query ended up like this and works now

```
SELECT "patternUuid", "urlName", title, json_agg(m."memberId") as members
FROM public.patterns p
JOIN members m
ON m."patternsUuid" = p."patternUuid"
GROUP BY p."patternUuid"
```

Thanks for the answers as you can see, I had to use the quotes around the uppercase columns like this: members."memberId"

Comment: Ok, it is good habit (not obligation) to accept answer which answers the question the best way. You can even accept self-answer, it is perfectly ok. It helps clarity as it means marking question as solved.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your columns are declared using [quoted identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS), hence the proper name of column in `members` table is `patternsUuid` (declared as `"patternsUuid"`) which is case sensitive. Identifier `members.patternsUuid` is unquoted so it is equivalent to `patternsuuid` which does not match real name.

> Quoting an identifier also makes it case-sensitive, whereas unquoted names are always folded to lower case. For example, the identifiers FOO, foo, and "foo" are considered the same by PostgreSQL, but "Foo" and "FOO" are different from these three and each other. (The folding of unquoted names to lower case in PostgreSQL is incompatible with the SQL standard, which says that unquoted names should be folded to upper case. Thus, foo should be equivalent to "FOO" not "foo" according to the standard. If you want to write portable applications you are advised to always quote a particular name or never quote it.)